# Вывод в PHP определенную строку из массива JSON соответствующей определенному объекту

Tags: php, json

Есть одномерный массив JSON

```
{"city":{"id":2013159,"name":"London", "list":
[
{"dt":1459360800,"main":{"temp":-6.55,"temp_min":-6.55,"temp_max":-2.34},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"ясно"}],
{"dt":1459425600,"main":{"temp":-8.55,"temp_min":-10.55,"temp_max":-4.34},"weather":[{"id":700,"main":"Cloud","description":"Облака"}],
{"dt":1459458000,"main":{"temp":-10.56,"temp_min":-15.55,"temp_max":-8.34},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Clear","description":"ясно"}]
]}
```

Данные объекта dt постоянно меняются "dt":1459425600 потом "dt":1459458000. Как вывести в PHP данные строки соответствующей определенному dt, например я хочу вывести из этого массива только те данные, которые соответствуют "dt":1459425600 это:

```
{"dt":1459425600,"main":{"temp":-8.55,"temp_min":-10.55,"temp_max":-4.34},"weather":[{"id":700,"main":"Cloud","description":"Облака"}]
```

p.s. не предлагать использование индекса, только через dt, который буду указывать я

Comment: декодируете json_decode в массив и дальше в цикле выбираете нужные данные. в чем проблема то?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

1. Массив ни разу не одномерный
2. В JSON допущены ошибки
3. Для таких целей лучше использовать MySQL или иные бд

Сам ответ:

**PHP**

```
function getRowByDt($object, $dt) {
  foreach($object['city']['list'] as $item) {
    if($item['dt'] == $dt) {
      return $item;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: не понятно, не получается, попытался вывести используя echo (getRowByDt()); выводит ошибку: PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for getRowByDt(), called in getForecast.php on line 104 and defined in getForecast.php on line 96
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for getRowByDt(), called in getForecast.php on line 104 and defined in getForecast.php on line 96
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: object in getForecast.php on line 97

Comment: наверно потому что нужно в функцию передать объект(массив) $object декодированного JSON и $dt строку, по которой ищем.
Подробнее о функциях: http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.user-defined.php
И об аргументах: http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php